# Minimal PDF example in PDF specification

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I took the minimal PDF example in the PDF specification from [PDF Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), copied it to NotePad, renamed the file to have the extension *.pdf*.

I can open it with other PDF viewer (PDF-XChange, SumatraPDF, MuPDF). But when I open it with Adobe Reader, it says the file is broken.

I am not sure if other viewers treat this "broken" file as blank file or not.

The file is supposed to display one blank page, since it is a minimal example.

In fact, I modify the minimal example. Because when I copy it from PDF specification to notepad, and open the .txt file by a Hex Editor, I see a new line in *.txt* file give me 2 space. For example,

```
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
```

gives me (in Hex Editor)

```
1 0 obj  << /Type /Catalog
```

which is (in hex values)

```
31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0A 3C 3C 20 2F 54 79 70
65 20 2F 43 61 74 61 6C 6F 67
```

The 2 spaces between `j` and `<` are `0D 0A`.

Hence I don't make new lines in NotePad, and modify the values in the `xref` part.

Below is the full code.

Do you know what's wrong with this example? Why does Adobe Reader say it is broken? Is this because I gave the wrong values in `xref`?

```
%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [4 0 R] /Count 1 >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 5 0 R /Resources << /ProcSet 6 0 R >> >> endobj 5 0 obj << /Length 35 >> stream … Page-marking operators … endstream endobj 6 0 obj [/PDF] endobj xref 0 7 0000000000 65535 f 0000000009 00000 n 0000000074 00000 n 0000000119 00000 n 0000000176 00000 n 0000000295 00000 n 0000000373 00000 n trailer << /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >> startxref 395 %%EOF
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**First:** when you 'copied' the example from the PDF specification, very likely a few things happened which made your copy to not work as expected:

- ...you didn't 'copy' by re-typing the example in a text editor, but
- ...you used copy'n'paste, using a PDF as the source file.

Depending on your text editor, that method probably caused the conversion of the newline convention to be changed from [cr]+[lf] to [cr] or vice-versa. This in turn means that the byte offset numbers in the object 'table of contents' (the '`xref`'-table) are no longer valid.

**Another problem** with the PDF source code you posted is that it doesn't now contain any linebreaks *at all*. Some viewers may be able to still silently parse the thing, but not all are. And it certainly is against the spec, because according to the spec, in chapter 7.5.2 it is clearly spelled out that

> "The first line of a PDF file shall be a header consisting of the 5 characters %PDF– followed by a version number of the form 1.N, where N is a digit between 0 and 7.

Your header violates that rule.

**Also,** the 'stream' in `5 0 obj` isn't any valid PDF code, it is just place holder text (`… Page-marking operators …`). Some viewers may be tilting when they come across such 'garbage'.

**Lastly,** your `startxref` value wasn't correct.

So here is a file that works. I repaired it in a text editor, and I put your original code as a comment after the `%%EOF` for comparison and reference:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids [4 0 R] /Count 1 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 5 0 R /Resources << /ProcSet 6 0 R >> >>
endobj
5 0 obj
<< /Length 35 >>
stream
… Page-marking operators …
endstream 
endobj
6 0 obj
[/PDF]
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000074 00000 n 
0000000119 00000 n 
0000000176 00000 n 
0000000295 00000 n 
0000000376 00000 n 
trailer 
<< /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
394
%%EOF

%% %PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [4 0 R] /Count 1 >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 5 0 R /Resources << /ProcSet 6 0 R >> >> endobj 5 0 obj << /Length 35 >> stream … Page-marking operators … endstream endobj 6 0 obj [/PDF] endobj xref 0 7 0000000000 65535 f 0000000009 00000 n 0000000074 00000 n 0000000119 00000 n 0000000176 00000 n 0000000295 00000 n 0000000373 00000 n trailer << /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >> startxref 395
```

Comment: Thanks Kurt, but why the value of startxref is 394 not 396. Isn't this value should be the byte offset of the character 'x' in `xref` in this file? It is 396 in a Hex Editor. But with 396, the file is broken, and 394 works. I don't know the reason.

Comment: @user565739: You should run `dd bs=1 skip=394 if=this.pdf`. That means you have skipped the first 394 bytes when dumping the file. Now the output should start with `xref` on a line by its own.

Comment: When I copy / pasted this, I had to change the single character "…" around "Page-marking operators" to the three character "..." and the startxref from 394 to 398. I suspect that when I copy/pasted the single character "..." was munged. By expanding to three, individual "." on either side of the stream, that added another 4 bytes which moved me to 398 from 394 for the start of the xref table.

Comment: I only get a blank page when I try to add some content, e.g., using "BT 10 50 Td (AwaY!)Tj ET" (with both instructions and start/end tags in separate lines) as stream for object 5 -and after adjusting the corresponding byte offsets. Preview opens it fine, but shows just a blank page. I'm using Preview ver 5 on a OX 10.6.8

Comment: I'll answer myself. I was looking for a real minimal, "hello world" PDF example. The example shown here is a minimal example in the sense that it is processed without erros, but doesn't print anything. In order to have some text a few things need to be added: 1) A hello-world stream for Obj 5, 2) a Font declaration as a new Obj 7 and 3) declaring this new font within the resources catalog of the page specification in Obj 4. Details in example H.2 of the PDF standard pointed to by the OP.

Comment: @MASL: A few more (hand-coded) PDF examples to play with can be found here: [github.com/angea/PDF101/tree/master/handcoded](https://github.com/angea/PDF101/tree/master/handcoded).